# Try/Catch breaks PHP script

Tags: php, try-catch

**SOLUTION:** I've been working on the iOS side of it at the same time and must have got the languages switched up. Instead of the `$`, I put `*`.

I am trying to get a `try{} catch{}` working in PHP. My code works when I remove the `try{} catch{}`. Once I put it back in, it breaks my script. I even tried making it empty in both the `try{} catch{}`, but it still crashes my script.

```
try {

}
catch (Exception *e) {

}
```

Is there a reason the `try{} catch{}` would cause the script to crash? When I run it in my browser it just shows a white screen.

I even went and made another empty PHP file and put this code in without the if statement. And still, it doesn't work. The page is still white. I had it `echo` in the `try`.

Comment: Can you at least show us your try/catch block? We're not psychics.

Comment: *e? should it be $e?

Comment: Activate error reporting and/or look at your error logs! Such errors aren't silent, they'll produce syntax error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your catch declaration is incorrect.

```
catch (Exception *e) {
```

Should be.

```
catch (Exception $e) {
```

The inaccurate code would cause a parse error, thus preventing the script from running at all, and producing a white screen.

Comment: OMG thank you! I've been working on the iOS side of it at the same time. Thank you! Did not even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe possibilities catch is not getting the object values. You should use it as:

```
try
{

some statement....
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 some statement...
}
```